# how to get markers in current view of map fragment?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have map with many markers , when users zoom to an area they can see some of this markers , how can I get list of this markers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Google Maps API's for android have [Visible Region](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/VisibleRegion) object, which contains such attributes as coordinates of four visible corners. You need to check if your Marker included in this borders, when `Camera` moves.

Fortunately, the Google developers did it for you:

`map.getBounds().contains(marker.getPosition())`

Comment: I have over 1000 markers , have i check all markers to see if they are in the visible region?

Comment: Yes, you have to loop through all of them.

Comment: this will make my app very slow , is there any other solution ?

Comment: do this in background task